# How to manage alarmManager when an app is killed (Android)

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have got an alarm that hit every 2 minutes (when the phone is not sleeping) and update a widget, it works good, but when the app is killed there isn't any alarm remaining so it doesn't work anymore. What can I do to manage this kill and keep my alarm working after that.

If you need more information, tell me. If you don't understand all, tell me too.

Thank's for answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure your alarm to be initialized on system boot complete intent (android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED) or similar intent that is dependable.

Create a broadcast receiver that consumes the following intent

```
if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"))
{
    AlarmManager aMgr = (AlarmManager) cx.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(cx, 0, new Intent(cx, ScheduleReceiver.class), 0);
    aMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, Thoth.Settings.ALARM_TRIGGER_AT_TIME, Thoth.Settings.ALARM_INTERVAL, pi);
}
```

ScheduleReceiver is the class that starts a service that updates the widget.

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing what happens when you kill the app, you may run into the same problem as I did.

On 2.2, if I kill the app in the Manage Applications view, my `AlarmManager` alarms for my app are removed automatically.

If the app dies because of an exception, then the Alarm continues to fire.